# typealias of generic class in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode6

I am trying to make a typealias of a generic type class as follows

```
class Cars<T> {
  ...
}

typealias SportCars = Cars
```

but I am getting a compile error as follow `Reference to generic type 'Cars' requires argument in <...>`

Comment: What's `Person`? Is there missing code?

Comment: Sorry it was made up example and typo. But my main point is how to make a typealias of a generic class

Comment: Not sure why this question is down voted? Can someone explain?

Comment: What is the point of the typealias here? Why not subclass?

Comment: typealias is just another name for a class where as subclassing will not allow me to pass Cars where SportsCars is needed.

Comment: You should read this: http://ericasadun.com/2016/04/15/triassic-park-the-swift-evolution/?utm_campaign=This%2BWeek%2Bin%2BSwift&utm_medium=email&utm_source=This_Week_in_Swift_83

Answer (score 8):

Right now, you can't do this with generics, as you've discovered.

```
typealias Foo = Array
// Doesn't work: Reference to generic type 'Array' requires argument in <...>
```

*The Swift Programming Language* iBook chapter *"Type Alias Declaration"* doesn't actually state anything about which types *cannot* be aliased. But it simply looks like that *partial types* (like generics without placeholders specified) are not allowed.

If you feel that this something Swift should do, file a Radar (bugreport) with Apple.

While researching for this answer, I noticed that the *partial type* problem not only affects `typealias` but is visible elsewhere as well:

```
let foo = Array.self
// Doesn't work: Cannot convert the expression's type 'Array<T>.Type' to type 'Array<T>.Type'
// … which is a very confusing error.

var bar: Array.Type
// Doesn't work: Reference to generic type 'Array' requires arguments in <...>

let bar: Array.Type = Array.self
// …/usr/bin/swift: Segmentation fault! :-)
```

All of these work if you specify the placeholder types:

```
typealias Foo = Array<Int> // Works
let foo = Array<Int>.self // Works
```

Comment: One pseudo-alternative: You can make a `typealias` of a protocol that contains associated type requirements (i.e., nested `typealias`es that an implementation can map to generics), but then you run into the problem that Swift will only let you use such protocols as generic constraints -- essentially the same issue as trying to use partial types.

Answer (score 6):

Possible workaround is to wrap type alias into class/struct:

```
struct SportCars<Y> {
  typealias T = Cars<Y>
}

/// Usage:
typealias Foo = SportCars<Int>.T
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the farthest you can go with `typealias` and generics is to create an alias of a specialized type, such as:

```
typealias SportsCar = Cars<Int>
```

If you need a different name for the same generic type, you can just subclass it:

```
class SportCars<T> : Cars<T> {}
```

it's not exactly an alias (you cannot use `Cars` when `SportCars` is expected, but the opposite is possible), but in a "controlled" environment it can work. I wouldn't use myself though.

Comment: I do not want to specify type. This restricts SportsCar to Int generic type only.