# In Swift, how to extend a typealias?

Tags: swift, extend, type-alias

I have a typealias:

```
typealias BeaconId = [String: NSObject]
```

I'd like to extend it by doing something like:

```
extension BeaconId {}
```

But this throws a compile error:

> Constrained extension must be declared on the unspecialized generic type 'Dictionary' with constraints specified by a 'where' clause

So I end up doing:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: StringLiteralConvertible, Value: NSObject {}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: I attempted to clean up your code and actually got this error: `constrained extension must be declared on the unspecialized generic type 'Dictionary' with constraints specified by a 'where' clause`

Comment: Yeah I got that as well, you can check out my full answer below. Basically it doesn't look like it's possible to extend specified generic types, only ones where the generic types haven't been set yet.

Comment: @Robert what I'd love to see in Swift 3 is not just constraints on protocols and inheritance but also on values so something like `extension SomeEnum where Self == .MyCase`. That way functionality could be defined only on specific enum cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, no.

Consider the following example:

```
typealias Height: Float

extension: Height {

}
```

Here `Height` is not a new type, it's just a label for `Float` so you're just extending `Float`. If you take a look at `Dictionary` it's `public struct Dictionary<Key : Hashable, Value> : CollectionType, DictionaryLiteralConvertible` so what you'd be trying to achieve with

```
extension BeaconID {}
```

is adding an extension to `Dictionary` with specific generic parameters.

What I would expect that you should be able to do is:

```
typealias BeaconID = Dictionary<Key: String, Value: NSObject>
```

but that also doesn't compile and that's because in Swift you can't typealias partial types (in other words generic types without specific generic parameter types. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24724501/1369331) for more info). A possible workaround for typealiasing generic types which is noted below the answer I linked to is

```
struct Wrapper<Key: Hashable, Value> {
    typealias T = Dictionary<Key, Value>
}
typealias BeaconID = Wrapper<String, NSObject>.T
```

but even then when you try to extend `BeaconID`, you get a compiler warning, which finally gets to the heart of the problem:

"Constrained extension must be declared on the unspecialized generic type 'Dictionary' with constraints specified by a 'where' clause"

Answer (score 16):

*Update at the time of Swift 4.2:* **you can now do this**

Example:

```swift
typealias KeyedNumbers = [String: Int]

extension KeyedNumbers {
    func squaredValue(forKey key: String) -> Int {
        return self[key]! * self[key]!
    }
}
```

With that (pretty useless) extension in place, you can do this:

```swift
let pairs = ["two": 2, "three": 3]
print("2 squared =", pairs.squaredValue(forKey: "two"))
```

And it will print

> 2 squared = 4

Comment: (here in Swift 5) it seems that the original type also gets the extension.  so eg `["two": 2, "three": 3].squaredValue(forKey: "two")` is valid.  Which you might not want in other situations.