# How do I define extension for Dictionary of specific type?

Tags: ios, swift

I have created `typealias`:

```
typealias Multilang = [String: Any]
```

Now I would like to extend that Dictionary with property `localized`. Is it possible?

How do I need to use it?

```
let dictionary: Multilang = ["en": "b", "pl": "d"]()
let value = dictionary.localized
```

I try to do it like this:

```
extension Dictionary where Dictionary: Multilang {
    var localized: String {
        print("self: \(self)")
        return "hello"
   }
}
```

but it doesn't work. Why?

> Type 'Dictionary(Key, Value)' constrained to non-protocol, non-class type 'Multilang' (aka 'Dictionary(String, Any)')

Answer (score 2):

You can write an extension like this:

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == Any {
    var localized: String {
        print("self: \(self)")
        return "hello"
    }
}
```

or:

```
extension Dictionary where Dictionary == Multilang
```

Comment: But this way it will be extended for every Dictionary of type `[String: Any]`, even for those not defined as `Multilang`.

Comment: Than try something like this: `extension Dictionary where Dictionary == Multilang`

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk that's not how typealiases work. The compiler exchanges all typealiases to the actual type they represent at __compile time__, so type aliases don't actually create a new type and the type system has no knowledge about typealiases. So what you are trying to do is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

It is (unfortunately) not possible to use `typealias` in this way, because it does not create a new type. For example, you can have `typealias Foo = [String: Any]` and `typealias Bar = [String: Any]`, but `Foo` and `Bar` still both the same type.

So either you have to extend all `[String: Any]` dictionaries, or you need to create a wrapper type (you also cannot subclass `Dictionary` because it is a `struct`). For example:

```
struct Multilang<Element> {
    var dictionary: [String: Element]
    var localized: Element? {
        return dictionary[currentLanguage]
    }
}
```

The downside is you need to define all the wrapper methods and properties that you want to use through `multilang.foo` syntax, but if it suffices to have just `multilang.localized`, you can do all the rest through `multilang.dictionary.foo`.

You can also implement `ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral` to make creating these objects easy:

```
extension Multilang: ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral {
    init(dictionaryLiteral elements: (String, Element)...) {
        dictionary = .init(elements) { $1 }
    }
}

let multilang: Multilang = [ "en": "English", "pl": "Polish" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 3 and above you can try this method to extend a dictionary of type `[String: Any]`.

```
extension Dictionary where Key: ExpressibleByStringLiteral, Value: Any {
    // Your extension code
    var localized: String {
    print("self: \(self)")
    return "hello"
}
```

[`ExpressibleByStringLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebystringliteral) is a protocol that `String` and `StaticString` types conform to.

You cannot apply it just to the type alias, because `Multilang` is just a label for `[String:Any]`, so even if you could extend it, it would extend all dictionaries of this type anyway.

Comment: Ok, but how can I use it *only* with `Multilang` types? Not with `[String: Any]`?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk I don’t think you can, because `Multilang` is just a label for `[String:Any]`, so even if you could extend it, it would extend all dictionaries of this type anyway.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33771563/8289095) for more information.